# what is proper way to create navigation bar with icons

Tags: css, navigation, sprite

How does one semantically marks up a navigation bar of icons + text, where text is below icons and icons are a sprite.

With two more conditions: navigation boxes are of different width and icon should serve as a link as well (be clickable)

Concrete example is @ www.emex.ru.

In other words: how does one convert
`<ul>

      <li>

        <a><img width=32 height=32/><br/>Link1</a>

      </li>

       <li>

        <a><img width=32 height=32/><br/>Link2</a>

      </li>

     </ul>`

to a version without `<img>` elements

Answer (score 0):

An unordered list is common for navigation menus. You can style the `ul` and `li` tags to space and align each link however you need. You should be setting a class or ID on the `li` tags and setting the background image position. A nice example is here

http://praveenfrancis.com/tutorials/create-a-simple-menu-with-css-sprite/

Answer (score 0):

Twitter bootstrap uses the `<i>` tag for doing this. See their [examples](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons).

So something like this:

```
<li>
  <a>
    <i class="icon-shoe"></i> 
    Shoe
  </a>
  <a>
    <i class="icon-balloon"></i> 
    Balloon
  </a>
</li>
```

And then in your CSS:

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
}

.icon-shoe {
  background-image: url("path/to/shoe/icon.png") no-repeat;
}

.icon-balloon {
  background-image: url("path/to/balloon/icon.png") no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: PS- if you want the icon to be above the text, just set `display: block;` instead of inline-block

Comment: I was actually trying to avoid this kind of obvious solution. And looking for a semantically correct way. And at the moment leaning towards 1px transparent gif img element with sprite background.

Answer (score -1):

becuase you'll be using images for your navigation its important that you add the `alt=""` tag in so google can see your links anchor text.